# change day part of datetime variable

Tags: asp.net

i am having one **date field** in my table and i am taking this **date field value** in my **datetime** variable.

eg:
**datetime dt=24/4/2014 12:00 am**

now i want to set only **day part** of this **datetime** variable means i want to change from **day 24** to **day 1** like this:

**dt=1/4/2014 12:00 am**

how to do this in **aspnet with c#?**

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new `DateTime` object using [`DateTime Constructor (Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In that constructor call use year,month, hour, minutes, seconds from original `dt` and explicitly pass `1` for the day part. Like:

```
DateTime dt = GetDateTimeFromDB(); //returns 24/4/2014 12:00 am
DateTime modifiedDt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
                                                // Pass 1 for day
```

Comment: thank u so so so so so so much for ur kind help.i realy appreciate that.thank u so much